# how to use firebase phone auth without create new uid

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

How to use firebase auth with phone number to verify phone number without create new uid i want to know just if the input code is correct or not
this the code that i used but it creates new uid

```
 manualVerification() {
print("My Id" + verificationId);
FirebaseAuth.instance
    .signInWithPhoneNumber(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode)
    .then((user) {
  print("Verification Successful");
  print("$user");
  setState(() {
    showStatus=3;
  });
  widget.onVerificationSuccess();
}).catchError((error) {
  print("Verification Failed Due to $error");
  widget.onVerificationFailure();
});
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of Firebase Authentication is to create a user account with a unique ID.  There's no way to separate out the process that just verifies the phone number.

Comment: ok , is there any service let me do it with flutter ?

Comment: That sounds like something you'll need to search for.  Stack Overflow isn't a place to seek product recommendations.

Comment: ok, another question please ,if i create new uid how to copy old children from old uid to new uid

Comment: If you have another question, please post it separately as a new question.